# Recursive backtracking maze generator (start/finish)

Tags: algorithm, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

So lets say the maze is already generated by the algorithm. How do you know where is the start and the end of the maze? Because at the beginning, you pick a random cell and you do not know where the maze ends after the algorithm is done

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information in your question.

Comment: Let's say you have a big maze and there is no more than 1 entrance and 1 exit, you can start anywhere and you'll eventually end up at theses two places.. but you need to able to KNOW that you're at the start/end.

Comment: You can pick any start and exit you like.

Comment: Well sorry if I was not specific, I made a new more detailed question about it, here :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167341/php-backtracking-maze-generation-converting-everything-to-2d-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - backtracking maze generation (converting everything to 2d array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167341/php-backtracking-maze-generation-converting-everything-to-2d-array)

Comment: Don't repost so quickly - you can (and should) edit your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say firstly your question is not very clear, you have not provided any specific explanation to what you require but I will still try to answer your question.

First thing to remember when writing a recursive function is that, it always requires a base condition, by base condition I mean a piece of code that will act as the endpoint otherwise your code will run for infinite time and your system could crash.

Now in your case, as you are inside a maze, so your base conditions will be when you hit the boundary of the maze, that's the time you will return you result back to the previous call.

Let's say for example I have a maze of 10X10. So in this case my walls will be at:-

```
(0,0)
(0,10)
(10,0)
(10,10)
```

So if I hit any one them, then I should return back. And your base case in terms of code would look something like this

```
if(x < 0 || x > 10 || y < 0 || y > 10)
{
   return <some_value>;
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Hope this helps!