# php - backtracking maze generation (converting everything to 2d array)

Tags: php, algorithm, minecraft, backtracking

Here generating a maze by backtracking works correctly but the thing is that I am trying to implement this in a pixel game (Minecraft)... so the problem is in drawing the maze. In this game, the size of the wall blocks should be the exact same as the size of an empty block/space, so the only solution I thought of was a bonus 2d array called totalmaze. Its purpose is to store both empty spaces and wall blocks so I made its size (x*3, y*3) and tried outputting the walls but unfortunately this causes a lot of problems such as too much empty space / blocked paths. Note : X, Z because it is a 3d maze.

If this was JavaScript and a simple app, I would just draw the walls as lines but in Minecraft, the sizes should be the same so this is where things become troublesome even though the algorithm is correct. Please help.

This is how I am trying to fix it but perhaps is not the way : https://prnt.sc/fbp88o

```
public function generateMaze($dim_x, $walls_height, $dim_z){

        $maze = array();
        $moves = array();

        $cell_count = $dim_x*$dim_z;

        for($position=0; $position<$cell_count; $position++){
            $maze[$position] = "01111"; // visited, NSEW
        }
        $pos=0;
        $maze[0]{0} = 1; /// initial
        $visited = 1;

        // determine possible directions
        while($visited<$cell_count){
            $possible = ""; 
            if((floor($pos/$dim_x)==floor(($pos-1)/$dim_x)) and ($maze[$pos-1]{0}==0)){
                $possible .= "W";
            }
            if((floor($pos/$dim_x)==floor(($pos+1)/$dim_x)) and ($maze[$pos+1]{0}==0)){
                $possible .= "E";
            }
            if((($pos+$dim_x)<$cell_count) and ($maze[$pos+$dim_x]{0}==0)){
                $possible .= "S";
            }
            if((($pos-$dim_x)>=0) and ($maze[$pos-$dim_x]{0}==0)){
                $possible .= "N";
            }
            if($possible){
                $visited ++;
                array_push($moves,$pos);
                $direction = $possible{rand(0,strlen($possible)-1)};
                switch($direction){
                    case "N":
                        $maze[$pos]{1} = 0;
                        $maze[$pos-$dim_x]{2} = 0;
                        $pos -= $dim_x;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        $maze[$pos]{2} = 0;
                        $maze[$pos+$dim_x]{1} = 0;
                        $pos += $dim_x;
                        break;
                    case "E":
                        $maze[$pos]{3} = 0;
                        $maze[$pos+1]{4} = 0;
                        $pos ++;
                        break;
                    case "W":
                        $maze[$pos]{4} = 0;
                        $maze[$pos-1]{3} = 0;
                        $pos --;
                        break;
                }
                $maze[$pos]{0} = 1;
            }
            else{
                $pos = array_pop($moves);
            }
        }
        $totalmaze = array();
        for($i=0; $i<$dim_x*3+1; $i++){
            $totalmaze[$i][0] = 1;
            $totalmaze[$i][$dim_z*3-1]=1;
        }
        for($i=0; $i<$dim_z*3+1; $i++){
            $totalmaze[0][$i] = 1;
            $totalmaze[$dim_x*3-1][$i]=1;
        }
        for($position=0; $position<$cell_count; $position++){
            $x = $position % $dim_x;
            $z = floor($position / $dim_x);
            if($maze[$position]{1} == 1){
                $totalmaze[$x*3+1][$z*3]=1;
            } 
            if($maze[$position]{2} == 1){
                $totalmaze[$x*3+1][$z*3+2]=1;
            }
            if($maze[$position]{3} == 1){
                $totalmaze[$x*3+2][$z*3+1]=1;

            }
            if($maze[$position]{4} == 1){
                $totalmaze[$x*3][$z*3+1]=1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Oh, and if you get confused because MC uses Java plugins, this is MCPE.

Comment: The main purpose is to store the entire maze (walls + empty spaces in the 2d array)

Comment: hope this gets answered eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's hard to explain the randomized Prim's algorithm in the comments. So I decided to post a new answer.

The wall cells in randomized Prim's algorithm actually have "directions". Consider the maze below where # indicates a wall and . indicates an empty cell (the positions are 0-based).

```
#####
#...#
###.#
#...#
#####
```

The wall positioned at (2, 1) links two cells (1, 1) and (3, 1), but not (2, 0) and (2, 2) (as both of them are walls). As soon as we pick our very first empty cell, the directions of all walls are determined. That is because the walls serve as edges in a graph, and the graph is determined when we choosw the first empty cell. You can draw some mazes on paper and see it yourself.

I've also written a python example of the randomized Prim's algorithm. Try to run it.

```
import random

SIZE = 21

# Fill the maze with walls
maze = [['#' for j in range(0, SIZE)] for i in range(0, SIZE)]

# Create an empty wall list
wall_list = []

# Check if the given position is in the maze and not on the boundary
def in_maze(row, col):
    return row > 0 and row < SIZE-1 and col > 0 and col < SIZE-1

# Add the neighboring walls of the cell (row, col) to the wall list
def add_walls(row, col):
    global maze, wall_list

    # It's a 4-connected grid maze
    dir = ((0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0))

    for k in range(0, len(dir)):
        # Calculate the neighboring wall position and the cell position
        wall_row = row + dir[k][0]
        wall_col = col + dir[k][1]
        cell_row = wall_row + dir[k][0]
        cell_col = wall_col + dir[k][1]

        # Make sure the wall grid is in the range of the maze
        if not in_maze(wall_row, wall_col) or not in_maze(cell_row, cell_col):
            continue

        # Add the wall and the neighboring cell to the list
        wall_list.append(((wall_row, wall_col), (cell_row, cell_col)))

# Pick a random grid first
cell_row = random.randint(1, SIZE-2)
cell_col = random.randint(1, SIZE-2)
maze[cell_row][cell_col] = '.'
add_walls(cell_row, cell_col)

while len(wall_list) > 0:
    # Pick a random wall
    id = random.randint(0, len(wall_list)-1)
    wall_row, wall_col = wall_list[id][0]
    cell_row, cell_col = wall_list[id][1]
    wall_list.pop(id)

    # Skip if it is no longer a wall
    if maze[wall_row][wall_col] != '#':
        continue
    # Skip if the two cells that the wall divides are visited
    if maze[cell_row][cell_col] == '.':
        continue

    # Make the two grid as passages
    maze[wall_row][wall_col] = '.'
    maze[cell_row][cell_col] = '.'

    # Add the neighboring walls
    add_walls(cell_row, cell_col)

# Print the maze
for row in maze:
    print(''.join(row))
```

You should get something like this

```
#####################
#.#.....#.#.#.......#
#.###.###.#.###.#.###
#.#.....#...#.#.#.#.#
#.###.#.###.#.###.#.#
#...#.#...#...#.....#
#.#.###.#####.#.#####
#.#.#.........#...#.#
###.#########.###.#.#
#.#...........#...#.#
#.#########.#.###.#.#
#.........#.#...#...#
#####.###.###.#####.#
#...#.#.#...........#
###.###.#####.###.###
#.......#.....#.....#
#.#.###.#####.#####.#
#.#.#...#...#.#.....#
#####.#.###.#####.###
#.....#.............#
#####################
```

Comment: I reimplemented it. It generates a bit weird mazes when SIZE is low number f.e < 10 but it works good

Comment: Also is SIZE supposed to be an odd number? can I work with Size X and Size Y?

Comment: Yes, you can generate any rectangular grid maze. It's recommended that SIZE_X and SIZE_Y are both odd, but not a must.

Comment: Here are the outputs : https://prnt.sc/fc0khj. Is this supposed to be legit? 1 - walls

Comment: There are supposed to be all walls around the maze. Your second and third maze seem to have empty grids on the border. If you don't want two-block-width walls, you can always set SIZE_X and SIZE_Y to odd numbers, and set (1, 1) as the first empty gird.

Comment: Alright thank you. Last question, how can I set a custom end of the maze?

Comment: You can select a grid on the border, and choose the nearest grid in the maze as the first empty grid.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a "block" maze there are better ways. Why not try some spanning-tree algorithm like Kruskal? Check the link below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Randomized_Kruskal.27s_algorithm

Comment: Can I use Prim's algorithm?

Comment: Yes. Prim is also a spanning-tree algorithm. There is also a randomized Prim algorithm in the link above. Just below section of randomized Kruskal algorithm.

Comment: I still do not understand how those help me to generate a block maze. For example http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/10/maze-generation-prim-s-algorithm this link shows the implementation of Prim's algorithm but the walls are still lines, not blocks. I am trying to implement it in a pixel game where absolutely every block ix 50x50 so I can't just draw the wall as a line. What I don't understand is how to convert the wall to a wall block 50x50 without ruining the maze

Comment: You can take a look at this :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLjOK671G9k. The walls should be the same size as the other blocks

Comment: Check this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Randomized_Prim.27s_algorithm , is the video beside the description the effect you want?

Comment: Yeah, exactly ^^

Comment: So you can try to follow the description in the link and implement it. It's a randomized Prim algorithm.

Comment: * If only one of the two cells that the wall divides is visited* that is assuming the walls are lines -.- Still dont know how to convert it to grid